# ThreeJS: WebGLRenderer acting very weird

Tags: three.js

I am facing very weird problem. I am running two threejs apps(same codebase only change in ui) in samsung note3. One app is running perfectly but in the other one webgl is not working Detector.webgl is return false.

ThreeJS version: `r79`.

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true
        });
```

Above code is giving this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getExtension' of null
at get (file:///android_asset/www/grid-assets/js/three.js:28022:20) 
at new THREE.WebGLRenderer (file:///android_asset/www/grid-assets/js/three.js:25056:13)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When WebGLRenderer is instantiated, WebGLExtensions is called to get various texture filtering support. The gl object which exists in any webGL enabled browser when a canvas object is created. Three.js calls something like:

```
gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
```

In your case, gl is returning Null. Since your error is not: "getContext is undefined", we know you have a good canvas. The problem is that it did not return a webGL context to the gl property when THREE.WebGLExtensions is called. So for some reason the browser is not providing Three.js with webGL access.

This could be a number of things. It may be the timing of objects loading onto a page, or something halting webGL access in the browser such as a hanging process. It's tough to say. I would check that you have the latest Android and android browser too. I would compare your working app with the failing app to try to identify a point of failure. Also reboot the device and have your failing app be the first thing you open to help rule out external processes causing webGL to fail.